# IMPORTRANGE timestamp import filter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, google-forms

I'm looking to have a form, which I expect will be used continuously over the next few quarters. I'm trying to create bi-weekly reports (in the form of new spreadsheets) that I can send out and keep records of.

This is as far as I've reached. The idea is that it will:

1. Import column D
2. If the person who submitted the form is Joe (column E) - I can make it work up to here.
3. **If it is between two dates (this is where I am unsure of what to do)**

   ```
   =filter(IMPORTRANGE("ExampleSheetURL", "Form Responses 1!D2:D30"),INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("ExampleSheetURL", "Form Responses 1!E2:E30"))="Joe",DATEVALUE(IMPORTRANGE("ExampleSheetURL", "Form Responses 1!A2:A30")>=DATEVALUE(TODAY())))
   ```

I need a way to import the timestamp and then convert it to a format that I can filter with.

This formula does not work and I've hit a mental roadblock, I'm hoping someone out there might have some ideas.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!forum/docs. has some pretty heavy hitters when using formulas and spreadsheets. they can probably help you with a formula.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I might have to check over there as well and I can report back here too.

Comment: If it helps at all, I know that using this formula:

=FILTER('Form Responses 1'!D2:D30,INDEX('Form Responses 1'!E2:E30)="Joe",DATEVALUE('Form Responses 1'!A2:A30)>DATEVALUE("04/25/2015"),DATEVALUE('Form Responses 1'!A2:A30)<DATEVALUE("04/29/2015"))

In the same spreadsheet, but different tab will work. I just need find a way for this to work in different spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer to my own question, but if someone would like to check it, I wouldn't be opposed:

=filter(IMPORTRANGE("ExampleSheetURL", "Form Responses 1!D2:D30"),INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("ExampleSheetURL", "Form Responses 1!E2:E30"))="Joe",INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("ExampleSheetURL", "Form Responses 1!A2:A30"))>DATEVALUE("04/25/2015 24:59:59"),INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("ExampleSheetURL", "Form Responses 1!A2:A30"))

I thought when importing the timestamp, I would need to import it using DATEVALUE, but it looks like using INDEX works for what I'm trying to accomplish here. I noticed that if I just set the date value without hours/minutes, it would count noon on the 27th as being > the 27th on it's own.

Rock on my friends.